# decode from unicode hex to string

Tags: javascript, decode

When I load my data from my model (asp.net model) if the string is in another language (Russian for example), I'm getting the unicode hex code of the chars. How can I convert them to a normal string?
The problem isn't from the javascript encoding, it's from loading it from the model. I tried using a lot of functions from the forum but none worked!
Here is an example of a value I should get:

```
Петър
```

And here is what I'm actually getting:

```
&#x41F;&#x435;&#x442;&#x44A;&#x440;
```

Comment: This lib might come in handy: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const sequence = '&#x41F;&#x435;&#x442;&#x44A;&#x440;'
const charCode = sequence.split(/[;\s]+/g)
  // remove empty
  .filter((v) => v)
  // &#x41F -> 0x41F -> number
  .map((v) => Number.parseInt(v.replace(/&#/, '0')))

console.log(
  String.fromCharCode(...charCode)
)
```

Comment: Why this doesn't work:
String.fromCharCode('@item.Name'.split(/[;\s]+/g).filter((v) => v).map((v) => Number.parseInt(v.replace(/&#/, '0'))));

Comment: @Kraeror Why is the quoted string `\"@item.Name\"` here?

Comment: The library that georg sent me works! I see that your method should work too. Thank you for your time!